# Query not using not exist

Tags: not-exists

How to rewrite the below query by not using not exist and the performance is better than using not exist

```
SELECT m.member
  FROM  member        m
 WHERE 1 = 1
   AND NOT EXISTS (
       SELECT NULL
         FROM history c
            , tender  t
      WHERE 1 = 1
        AND c.card_type        =  t.tender_type
        AND c.member           =  m.member
       AND 1 = 1 )
    AND 1 = 1;
```

Thanks is advance for all your help.

Comment: I am trying to improve the performance of the process that uses the query. Member table has 10 million + records and the query brings out the list of members do not exist in the history table and the tender/source will be LEV

Comment: SELECT m.member
  FROM  member        m
 WHERE 1 = 1
   AND NOT EXISTS (
       SELECT NULL
         FROM history c
            , tender  t
      WHERE 1 = 1
        AND c.card_type        =  t.tender_type
        AND c.member           =  m.member
        AND t.client_type      = 'LEV'
       AND 1 = 1 )
    AND 1 = 1;

Answer (score 0):

You haven't described what problem you're trying to solve.

It looks like maybe you're trying to get a list of members who have no history?

```
select 
    m.member
from 
    member m
    left join history c on c.member = m.member
where
    c.member is null
```

Adding clarification to your question might help. Can you provide the DDL of your tables and explain in english what you would like the query to return?